# Count occurences of a row with pandas in python

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

I have a pandas data frame with thousands of rows and 4 columns. i.e.:

```
A B C D 
1 1 2 0
3 3 2 1
3 1 1 0
....
```

Is there any way to count how many times a certain row occurs? For example how many times can [3,1,1,0] be found, and return the indices of those rows?

Comment: There are plenty of ways of doing this, including most obviously a trivial linear search - so trivial I suspect nobody would ask on here.   I suspect this is not precisely what you're looking for?  Is this more about finding duplicates in the general case?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're only looking for one row, then I might do something like

```
>>> df.index[(df == [3, 1, 1, 0]).all(axis=1)]
Int64Index([2, 3], dtype=int64)
```

--

Explanation follows.  Starting from:

```
>>> df
   A  B  C  D
0  1  1  2  0
1  3  3  2  1
2  3  1  1  0
3  3  1  1  0
4  3  3  2  1
5  1  2  3  4
```

We compare against our target:

```
>>> df == [3,1,1,0]
       A      B      C      D
0  False   True  False   True
1   True  False  False  False
2   True   True   True   True
3   True   True   True   True
4   True  False  False  False
5  False  False  False  False
```

Find the ones which match:

```
>>> (df == [3,1,1,0]).all(axis=1)
0    False
1    False
2     True
3     True
4    False
5    False
```

And use this boolean Series to select from the index:

```
>>> df.index[(df == [3,1,1,0]).all(axis=1)]
Int64Index([2, 3], dtype=int64)
```

If you're not counting occurrences of one row, but instead you want to do this repeatedly for each row and so you really want to simultaneously locate all the rows, there are much faster ways than doing the above again and again.  But this should work well enough for one row.

Comment: Thanks for your answer DSM. I've tried it and is looks to be what I need. However, my initial data frame has 10 million rows and the df.index results seem to only show matches in the first 100,000 rows. Is there anything I could do to have it go through the whole data set?

Comment: Sorry it worked now! perfect, this is exacly what I need. many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

First create a sample array:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> x = [[1, 1, 2, 0],
... [3, 3, 2, 1],
... [3, 1, 1, 0],
... [0, 1, 2, 3],
... [3, 1, 1, 0]]
```

Then create a view of the array where each row is a single element:

```
>>> y = x.view([('', x.dtype)] * x.shape[1])
>>> y
array([[(1, 1, 2, 0)],
       [(3, 3, 2, 1)],
       [(3, 1, 1, 0)],
       [(0, 1, 2, 3)],
       [(3, 1, 1, 0)]], 
      dtype=[('f0', '<i8'), ('f1', '<i8'), ('f2', '<i8'), ('f3', '<i8')])
```

Do the same thing with the element you want to find:

```
>>> e = np.array([[3, 1, 1, 0]])
>>> tofind = e.view([('', e.dtype)] * e.shape[1])
```

And now you can look for the element:

```
>>> y == tofind[0]
array([[False],
       [False],
       [ True],
       [False],
       [ True]], dtype=bool)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use MultiIndex, when it's sorted, it is faster to find the count:

```
s = StringIO("""A  B  C  D
1  1  2  0
3  3  2  1
3  1  1  0
3  1  1  0
3  3  2  1
1  2  3  4""")
df = pd.read_table(s,delim_whitespace=True)
s = pd.Series(range(len(df)), index=pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays(df.values.T))
s = s.sort_index()
idx = s[3,1,1,0]
print idx.count(), idx.values
```

output:

```
2 [2 3]
```