# Duplicate rows in pandas DF

Tags: pandas, count, duplicates, row

I have a DF in Pandas, which looks like:

```
Letters Numbers
A       1
A       3
A       2
A       1
B       1
B       2
B       3
C       2
C       2
```

I'm looking to count the number of similar rows and save the result in a third column. For example, the output I'm looking for:

```
Letters Numbers Events
A       1       2
A       2       1
A       3       1
B       1       1
B       2       1
B       3       1
C       2       2
```

An example of what I'm looking to do is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15453237/count-occurences-of-a-row-with-pandas-in-python). The best idea I've come up with is to use `count_values()`, but I think this is just for one column. Another idea is to use [`duplicated()`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.duplicated.html), anyway I don't want construct any `for`-loop. I'm pretty sure, that a Pythonic alternative to a for loop exists.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can groupby these two columns and then calculate the sizes of the groups:

```
In [16]: df.groupby(['Letters', 'Numbers']).size()
Out[16]: 
Letters  Numbers
A        1          2
         2          1
         3          1
B        1          1
         2          1
         3          1
C        2          2
dtype: int64
```

To get a DataFrame like in your example output, you can reset the index with `reset_index`.

Comment: Could you provide the extra code for implementing the `reset_index()` to get the desired output. I am trying to do the dame thing with a few more columns that I want to group by.

Comment: @oliversm `df.groupby(['Letters', 'Numbers']).size().reset_index(drop=True)`

Answer (score 6):

You can use a combination of `groupby`, `transform` and then `drop_duplicates`

```
In [84]:

df['Events'] = df.groupby('Letters')['Numbers'].transform(pd.Series.value_counts)
df.drop_duplicates()
Out[84]:
  Letters  Numbers  Events
0       A        1       2
1       A        3       1
2       A        2       1
4       B        1       1
5       B        2       1
6       B        3       1
7       C        2       2
```

Comment: Thank you, but I can not understand at the moment the syntax of groupby method. Should be not groupby(['Letters', 'Numbers'])?

Comment: No, this groups only by Letters, and then counts for each group the occurences of the values in Numbers. This then results in the same as grouping by both columns and calculating the size of the groups.

Comment: @joris ignore last comment