# New column showing number of occurrences of unique rows

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to work out how to use Pandas to add a new column showing the number of occurrences of unique rows and then delete any duplicates.  I can get close to this output when not using pandas with:

```
sort <inputfile | uniq -c
```

or via excel with a new column showing countif or similar.  Has anyone done this in Pandas and would be able to help please?

Comment: adding the pandas code you have tried and a sample of the input would help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`df.drop_duplicates()`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html) to drop duplicate rows.
In addition, if you want to have a new DataFrame showing you which rows are duplicate call [`df.duplicated()`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/generated/pandas.DataFrame.duplicated.html).

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# coding: utf-8

import pandas as pd

# define DataFrame using same sample data
d = {'i': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 1, 4, 9, 10 ], 'j': [4, 12, 13, 1 ,15, 16, 4, 1, 19, 20]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

# print sample DataFrame
print(df)

# print DataFrame with dropped duplicate rows
print(df.drop_duplicates())

# print DataFrame containing `True` for each duplicate row, see doc for further options
print(df.duplicated())
```

---

**Edit** (due to comments):

After defining the DataFrame `df`, try the [following](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25619297/duplicate-rows-in-pandas-df):

```
df.groupby(['i', 'j']).size()
```

[`.groupby()`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) groups both columns, whereas [`.size()`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.size.html?highlight=size#pandas.DataFrame.size) returns the number of elements in underlaying data.

Comment: Thanks for the input but I need to add a new column showing the number of occurrences for the unique rows before deleting any duplicates. The code above shows me when there is a duplicate row but does not give a new column showing number of occurrences of unique rows.

Comment: @adele: Do you want to have a additional column containing to values? One counter for unique and antoher counter for duplicate rows?

Comment: Hi Albert.  The additional column is to show how many times the duplicate was seen.  So if a duplicate row is seen 7 times the number 7 would be used and one row would remain with the other six deleted ideally.  Thanks!