# counting the first occurence of duplicates in a dataframe

Tags: pandas, dataframe

```
    Agent Amount repeat_count
    A20   50 USD
    A30   70 USD
    A60   80 USD
    A30   70 USD   1
    A20   57 USD
    A20   50 USD
```

SO, above is a small sample of my dataframe. I need to count sequential duplicates i.e. those agents which are transferring the same amount as they did in the previous transaction. 
For instance , A30 is transferring amount 70 USD twice in a row and hence I need to store the count.
Even A20 is sending amount 50 USD twice , but between that it is also sending amount 57 USD . So , I do not want to store its count. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Very similar to this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/25619297/2087463).

Comment: df.duplicated can give me duplicated rows but I am hitting a wall in figuring out how to count only the first occurence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's use a larger example:

```
Agent Amount
A20   50
A30   70
A60   80
A30   70
A20   57
A20   50
A30   70
A30   80
A30   70
```

As usual with such a problem, we will use `groupby` to work on each agent separately, so we can solve the problem for a single agent first. Let:

```
df1 = df[df.Agent == 'A30']
```

The following will find when the same amount is repeated:

```
df1.Amount.shift() == df1.Amount
```

So you can count the number of occurrences with a `cumsum`:

```
In [11]: (df1.Amount.shift() == df1.Amount).cumsum()
Out[11]: 
1    0
3    1
6    2
7    2
8    2
```

Let's apply the above solution to the original dataframe:

```
In [12]: df.groupby('Agent').apply(
             lambda df1: (df1.Amount.shift() == df1.Amount).cumsum()
         )
Out[12]: 
Agent   
A20    0    0
       4    0
       5    0
A30    1    0
       3    1
       6    2
       7    2
       8    2
A60    2    0
```

In order to merge the result with the original dataframe, we need to drop the first level of the index (the agents):

```
repeat_count = df.groupby('Agent').apply(
                   lambda df1: (df1.Amount.shift() == df1.Amount).cumsum()
               )
pd.concat([df, repeat_count.reset_index(level=0, drop=True)], axis=1)
```

The function `concat` will merge based on index values, so the results in `repeat_count` are aligned with the original dataframe.

Comment: Hi , For the most part this looks like a very elegant solution. I did not know about the cumsum() function before. I am not sure whether this will work to count only the first occurence of a a duplicate.

Comment: If my answer worked for you, you can accept it. If you find a case that needs tweaking let me know.

Comment: @vishalbhatt remember [you get points for accepting too](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)!

Comment: Hi, The solution worked just fine. cumsum() is the most efficient way to count consecutive occurences. many thanks.